# Check depend on service is avaiable when springboot app start up

Tags: postgresql, jpa

I have face a issue now, I have wrote a springboot microservice base on JPA to expose some table and provide CRUD restful api for it.

But now I have to check dependcy of my service such as the postgresql server is ready(deployed in docker in K8s env and run as a pod with a avaiable ingres hostname and port), and if postgresq is up, I also need check the database has been created by some shellscript in postgresql server.

If check failed, my microservice should suspend and retry again later (maybe after few mins),when the postgresql is ready(server is up, database is created) myservice start up normally and provider service as wish.

I want to know any best practice can archieve this purpose?

Comment: What you wrote sounds very straight-forward. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

when I ask this question, I did not got the best practice to implemented this.

After some research, I believe we should make sure the postgresql database service is ready and it initilized the database by itself such as some shellscript when the postgresql container start up.

then after postgresql container is up, my microservice can use JDBC connnected to this database instance and use flyway or other database initilization tools has been intergrated in spring-boot framework to create table and insert out-of-box data.

The microservice is not a good place to handle the database creation.